# Touchpad Not Working On My Samsung Chromebook Pro

Tags: touchpad, chromebook

I am a little bit stuck. I have installed Ubuntu on my Samsung Chromebook Pro. Everything is working fine but the touchpad. I have tried to add the touchpad driver and I have also entered in several commands in the terminal but it will still not work. Also, I am running Ubuntu 17.04 and I am using a Bluetooth mouse. any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: This an an issue with all Chromebooks running Ubuntu that I know of. I'm using a Parrot Chromebook to run Ubuntu and it doesn't work either; I'm having to carry around a keyboard with touchpad everywhere I use it. Hugh Greenberg, [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjAir7c4Z3VAhXHYiYKHafPCJwQFggrMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fhugegreenbug%2Fxf86-input-cmt&usg=AFQjCNGUN6n0mPWLxoek5IFw2k4vR89Dxw) has ported the ChromeOS touchpad driver to Linux but I don't know what to do with it to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will try it out right now.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried what you said and it did not work. I downloaded the deb file and installed it but my touchpad is still not working.

Comment: That's what happened to me. If I knew anything about drivers, I'd fork it and update everything but I've only _not_ been using ChromeOS for about two months.